# Why does a custom PPA offers to update gnome keyring?

Tags: updates, security, ppa, gnome-keyring

I installed this PPA only to add some control panel widget. But it suggests some updates I don't expect from it. Is this safe to install?

[image: LP-PPA-atareao-atareao]

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to ask the person who maintains the PPA why they are adding that to the PPA. A person who runs a PPA can put whatever they want into it.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)